# How to do random generator of elements of list?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

I have list:

```
    List quotes = [
        "Lmao this is text",
        "Okay okay go to next",
        "So, we are the champion nanana",
        "Gagagagaga",
        "What does the fox say?"
      ];

var _index = new Random();
```

And I want to create random text generator from my elements of list.
I use statefull in flutter and when I tap the button, I want new random element from my list.
Example of my code:

```
 children: [
                Text(quotes[_index]),
    
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                      child: FlatButton.icon(
                          onPressed: _showFate(),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.casino),
                          label: Text("New words!", style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                          ),)),
_showFate() {
    setState(() {
      _index.nextInt(5);
    });
```

Why it does not work I do not understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_index` should be an `int` not `Random` and you should also reassign the random value to `_index` in the `setState`

Check this out.

```
int _index = 0;

_showFate(){
  setState(() {
   _index = Random().nextInt(5);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `_index.nextInt(quotes.length)` inside your text widget and call setState to update:

```dart
children: [
                Text(quotes[_index.nextInt(quotes.length)]),
    
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                      child: FlatButton.icon(
                          onPressed: _showFate(),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.casino),
                          label: Text("New words!", style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                          ),)),
_showFate() {
    setState(() {});
}
```